# Interpolated variable within variable

Tags: variables, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, terraform

Quick one.. I'm working on a TF file for Google Cloud Kubernetes Engine.

Anyone know how I can pass the following:

```
pd_name = "${google_compute_disk.${var.app_name}.name}"
```

Trying to feed an interpolated variable into another variable. I didn't think it would would when I was writing it.

Any ideas?

Thanks
Jon

Comment: How many `google_compute_disk` resources are you defining? One? What about `resource "google_compute_disk" "this" { .. }" and then referring to using that "well known" identifier, regardless of how the app is called?

Comment: For this deployment at the moment, it's just going to be a single disk & volume. However, there may be more added. Probably one for the DB, which will may be claimed by a different node. So I was hoping to make it configurable from tfvars.

Comment: Then call one `app` and the other one `db` ;)

Comment: My thought was to make the TF files completely agnostic and portable. Then from project to project, the only changes would be to the tfvars file. If it’s not possible to pass multiple variables in a single string then I guess I’ll have to name them in the TF File.

Comment: Terraform doesn't allow the interpolation of variable into another variable, I tried it and gaved up... If you find a way to do it I'm interested.
To make tf file agnostic, name the resources disk-{1,2,3,4} that is the easiest way to have something looking agnostic.

Comment: I don't have anything I can try this on right now, and I'm also a little unclear on how you're trying to use this, but what about this?
`locals {
  pd_name = "${format("google_compute_disk.%v.name", var.app_name)}"
}`

Comment: @MikeFrank that just gives you the string `google_compute_disk.foo.name` (assuming `app_name` = `foo`) and not the name attribute from the resource. It's not currently possible to do what the OP wants and they should rethink what they're trying to do as @StephenKing has suggested.

Comment: I thought that had worked initially as it didn't fail on a `terraform init` as it previously did. But it does now fail a `terraform plan` with... `Error: Error asking for user input: Error parsing address 'kubernetes_persistent_volume_claim.${var.app_name}': invalid resource address "kubernetes_persistent_volume_claim.${var.app_name}"`

Comment: I agree with the folks who say you may need to rethink your approach. We had issues with trying to build reusable modules because of the limitations of the "language". We built a command line tool that uses a template generator to work around this problem. I'm hoping the new language features in 0.12 will resolve these issues.

Comment: I have changed the thought process and approached it in a different way. Hopefully, as you say, the limitations of the language will reduce in later versions.